# Error in Reading Kafka Topic using Flink Table API

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to apache flink and was following the [article](https://thecodinginterface.com/blog/kafka-source-sink-with-apache-flink-table-api/) to prepare a small working solution of kafka and flink togther.

**I was able to :**

1. Run Confluent Kafka and zookeeper cluster using docker
2. Start Apache Flink Cluster (1.17.0)
3. Start the Kafka Producer which was producing messages every second

**I was not able to :**

1. Display kafka topic streaming data using Flink Consumer

**Question:** How can I display the streaming data from kafka Topic using print() ? I want to visualize the data before sending it to a sink.

**Code:**

```
import os

from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.table import StreamTableEnvironment, EnvironmentSettings, TableEnvironment
from pyflink.table.expressions import *


def main():


    # Create streaming environment
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

    settings = EnvironmentSettings.in_streaming_mode()

    # create table environment
    tbl_env = StreamTableEnvironment.create(stream_execution_environment=env,
                                            environment_settings=settings)

    # add kafka connector dependency
    kafka_jar = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                            'flink-sql-connector-kafka-1.17.0.jar')

    tbl_env.get_config()\
            .get_configuration()\
            .set_string("pipeline.jars", "file://{}".format(kafka_jar))

    #######################################################################
    # Create Kafka Source Table with DDL
    #######################################################################
    src_ddl = """
        CREATE TABLE sales_usd (
            seller_id VARCHAR,
            amount_usd DOUBLE,
            sale_ts BIGINT
        ) WITH (
            'connector' = 'kafka',
            'topic' = 'sales-usd',
            'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:9092',
            'properties.group.id' = 'sales-1',
            'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
            'format' = 'json'
        )
    """

    tbl_env.execute_sql(src_ddl)

    # create and initiate loading of source Table
    tbl = tbl_env.from_path('sales_usd').select(col("seller_id"),col("amount_usd"),col("sale_ts"))

    print('\nSource Schema')
    tbl.print_schema()
    table_result = tbl_env.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM sales_usd")
    print(table_result.print())
```

I am getting below error:

```
 % python sales_processor.py

Source Schema
(
  `seller_id` STRING,
  `amount_usd` DOUBLE,
  `sale_ts` BIGINT
)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/docker_project/codinginterface_kafka_flink/sales_processor.py", line 129, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Desktop/docker_project/codinginterface_kafka_flink/sales_processor.py", line 65, in main
    print(table_result.print())
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyflink/table/table_result.py", line 219, in print
    self._j_table_result.print()
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o107.print.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to fetch next result
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:109)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.hasNext(CollectResultIterator.java:80)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.connectors.CollectDynamicSink$CloseableRowIteratorWrapper.hasNext(CollectDynamicSink.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.table.utils.print.TableauStyle.print(TableauStyle.java:120)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableResultImpl.print(TableResultImpl.java:153)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch job execution result
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:184)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.next(CollectResultFetcher.java:121)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultIterator.nextResultFromFetcher(CollectResultIterator.java:106)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1915)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:182)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.lambda$getJobExecutionResult$3(MiniClusterJobClient.java:141)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApplyStage(CompletableFuture.java:614)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenApply(CompletableFuture.java:1983)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniClusterJobClient.getJobExecutionResult(MiniClusterJobClient.java:138)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.collect.CollectResultFetcher.getAccumulatorResults(CollectResultFetcher.java:181)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:256)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:247)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:240)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:738)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:715)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:78)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:477)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:309)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:307)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.connector.base.source.reader.fetcher.SingleThreadFetcherManager.<init>(Lorg/apache/flink/connector/base/source/reader/synchronization/FutureCompletingBlockingQueue;Ljava/util/function/Supplier;Lorg/apache/flink/configuration/Configuration;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.fetcher.KafkaSourceFetcherManager.<init>(KafkaSourceFetcherManager.java:72)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.createReader(KafkaSource.java:163)
        at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.createReader(KafkaSource.java:135)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SourceOperator.initReader(SourceOperator.java:286)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceOperatorStreamTask.init(SourceOperatorStreamTask.java:94)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:692)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:669)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:935)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:904)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:728)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:550)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help..!!

All possible approaches

Comment: Hi @Jatin. Were you able to fix this? Even I'm facing this error. The version update from 1.16.1 to 1.17.0 has caused us this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `collect()` method on the Table object to retrieve the data as a list of Rows and then use the `print()`

ex :

```
 rows = tbl_env.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM sales_usd").collect()
```

Comment: I tried the below approach but its not working :  `table_result = tbl_env.execute_sql("SELECT * FROM sales_usd").collect()

    for row in table_result:
        print(row.get_fields_by_names("seller_id"),row.get_fields_by_names("amount_usd"))` Is it really possible to print the streaming data from kafka topic using Table API ? or we can send it to some sink and visualize the sink ? Thanks for your comment